# Is there a universally recognizable, OS agnostic glyph for the Super key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, symbols, operating-systems

The reason I'm asking is trivial, but I can't come up with a better place to ask.

I bought a [keyboard](http://www.coolermaster.com/peripheral/keyboards/masterkeys-pro-s/) that has Super keys with the vendor logo printed on them.

I've been meaning to replace them with the Windows key but I was wondering if there was another symbol I could use since I'm not really tied to Windows.

Comment: You may use something like ♃, the glyph of Jupiter, or the I Ching hexagram for "before completion".

Comment: I'd use the OS X Command key symbol ⌘ – while it's _sort of_ associated with OS X, that's practically just because nobody else uses it. It's not like Apple has a trademark on it, to my knowledge. Plus, it has a standardized Unicode code point! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looped_square

Comment: Have you considered using the user agent to determine what operating system the user is on, then changing the symbol for the super key accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

**Common symbols for the super key are OS-specific.**

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys) elsewhere on StackExchange and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)) it doesn't seem like there is an icon other than the Windows and Mac platform specific ones. If you know which OS you will use or have a preference, I would recommend one of those.

An alternative could be to use the obsolete [meta key symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key), which was a diamond: ◆. It basically worked the same way as the Windows or Mac command keys, but it is unlikely that someone would recognize that symbol on a modern keyboard.

Comment: Agreed. *The very fact that OP is asking this question* supports the idea that there effectively isn't. Picking the diamond might be a good solution, as long as there's an explanation of what it represents.

Answer (score 2):

#### I'd use the OS X Command key symbol, [⌘](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looped_square).

Yes, it's traditionally associated with OS X, but that's just because nobody else uses it. I don't believe Apple has a trademark on it or anything like that.

As an added bonus, it even has a Unicode code point – U+2318.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any universal super key button design due to the history of computers' competition and growth.

Because I don't like Windows' principle and occasionally swap to GNU/Linux platforms, I replaced my superkey buttons to blank ones.